# Learning about LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

### Overview

One of the things I've asked a lot about on this site is [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx). The questions I've asked have been wide and varied and often don't have much context behind them. So in an attempt to consolidate the knowledge I've acquired on Linq I'm posting this question with a view to maintaining and updating it with additional information as I continue to learn about LINQ.

I also hope that it will prove to be a useful resource for other people wanting to learn about LINQ.

### What is LINQ?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx):

> The LINQ Project is a codename for a
> set of extensions to the .NET
> Framework that encompass
> language-integrated query, set, and
> transform operations. It extends C#
> and Visual Basic with native language
> syntax for queries and provides class
> libraries to take advantage of these
> capabilities.

What this means is that LINQ provides a standard way to query a variety of datasources using a common syntax.

### What flavours of LINQ are there?

Currently there are a few different LINQ providers provided by Microsoft:

- [Linq to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) which allows you to execute queries on any IEnumerable object.
- [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) which allows you to execute queries against a database in an object oriented manner.
- [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) which allows you to query, load, validate, serialize and manipulate XML documents.
- [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) as suggested by [Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322/all-about-linq#33588)
- [Linq to Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399399.aspx)

There are quite a few others, many of which are listed [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/vardi/archive/2008/10/09/the-linq-list-projects.aspx).

### What are the benefits?

- Standardized way to query multiple datasources
- Compile time safety of queries
- Optimized way to perform set based operations on in memory objects
- Ability to debug queries

### So what can I do with LINQ?

[Chook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489/ch00k) provides a way to [output CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/csv-string-handling#4441)
[Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) shows how to [remove duplicates from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array#9685)
Bob gets a [distinct ordered list from a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59/how-do-i-get-a-distinct-ordered-list-of-names-from-a-datatable-using-linq#62)
[Marxidad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1659/marxidad) shows how to [sort an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486/sorting-an-ilist-in-c#15495)
Dana gets help implementing a [Quick Sort Using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185072/learning-linq-quicksort)

### Where to start?

**A summary of links from [GateKiller's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050/beginners-guide-to-linq) are below**:
Scott Guthrie provides an [intro to Linq on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)
An overview of [LINQ on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

**[ChrisAnnODell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1758/ChrisAnnODell) suggests checking out:**

- [Hooked on Linq](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/MainPage.ashx)
- [101 Linq Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)
- [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

### What do I need to use LINQ?

Linq is currently available in VB.Net 9.0 and C# 3.0 so you'll need Visual Studio 2008 or greater to get the full benefits. (You could always write your code in notepad and compile using MSBuild)

There is also a tool called [LinqBridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652/querying-like-linq-when-you-dont-have-linq#7710) which will allow you to run Linq like queries in C# 2.0.

### Tips and tricks using LINQ

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858/coolest-c-linqlambdas-trick-youve-ever-pulled) has some tricky ways to use LINQ

Comment: +1 for a great post and the reference to ScottGu's blog. It's a great resource and where I initially learned LINQ.

Comment: Hooked On LINQ goes to some japanese site. The google translate talks about rimming and other butt stuff that's nsfw. :S I can't edit it for some reason, though.

Answer (score 13):

LINQ to entities:

- [Video walkthroughs](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/05/20/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos.aspx)
- [Channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/ADONET-Entity-Framework-What-How-Why/)
- [Entity framework FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/pages/entity-framework-faq.aspx)
- [Entity framework performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/03/27/ado-net-entity-framework-performance-comparison.aspx)

I've got a lot more I [tagged on Delicious.com](http://delicious.com/mrshrinkray/entityframework).

Comment: Why this delicious.com redirects to an extension name called Dmail on chrome store? o.O You mean https://del.icio.us/ instead?

Answer (score 7):

Mention LINQ to Entities since ADO.NET Entity Framework will be an important .NET module.

Answer (score 5):

### A few LINQ Tips:

- Apply filters before a join to improve query performance
- Filter LINQ queries using object reference comparison
- Apply aggregates to empty collections in LINQ to SQL queries
- Delay loading a property in LINQ to SQL
- Use table-valued functions with eager loading turned on
- Put joins in the correct order in a LINQ to Objects query
- Compose a LINQ query inside a loop

http://www.aspnetpro.com/articles/2009/04/asp200904zh_f/asp200904zh_f.asp

Answer (score 4):

Get the book ***Linq in Action*** it is an easy read for a coding book and really teaches you how to use Linq and the new features of .NET 3.5 some of the cool parts they put in for the language.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, an overlooked, but important, benefit is the coding efficiency of LINQ, e.g how much can be accomplished with so little code. I personally find the query syntax easy to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

Some caveats about using **LINQ to SQL**:

[Has Microsoft really killed LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253263/has-microsoft-really-killed-linq-to-sql)

[Is LINQ to SQL DOA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

There's also some [controversy](http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=1457) about the first version of **Entity Framework**, including a [petition](http://efvote.wufoo.com/forms/ado-net-entity-framework-vote-of-no-confidence/).

Answer (score 3):

I think, the answer to "What flavors of LINQ are there?" is incomplete.
First of all, you can create your own "flavor". Yes, it is an advanced task, but there are a lot of different LINQ implementations now.

Here is the list of existing LINQ providers (plus some more resources on learning LINQ) on Charlie Calvert's blog: [Links to LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2006/10/05/Links-to-LINQ.aspx).

And also there is an excellent series of blog posts by Matt Warren on how to create your own LINQ Provider: [LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/pages/linq-links.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents , Read chapters  "11 Query expressions and LINQ to Objects" and "12 LINQ beyond collections" in "C# in Depth" book  to understand how LINQ works.

Answer (score 0):

**For Linq Practice**

If you want some practice on LINQ with exercises and answers, really easy to set up and, in my opinion, awesome:

https://github.com/walkhard/linq-exercises

Download from git, open in Visual Studio. Your job is to make the tests pass.

[disclosure: i learned some linq from it and I contribute to the project so yeah i think it's an awesome, fast and efficient way to learn.]