# Good explanation of "Combinators" (For non mathematicians)

Tags: function, lambda, combinators, y-combinator

Anyone got a good explanation of "combinators" (Y-combinators etc. and **NOT** [the company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_Combinator_(company)))?

I'm looking for one for the practical programmer who understands recursion and higher-order functions, but doesn't have a strong theory or math background.

(Note: that I'm talking about [these things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus))

Answer (score 39):

Unless you're deeply into theory, you can regard the Y combinator
as a neat trick with functions, like monads.

Monads allow you to chain actions, the Y combinator allows you to
define self-recursive functions.

Python has built-in support for self-recursive functions, so you
can define them without Y:

```
> def fun():
>  print "bla"
>  fun()

> fun()
bla
bla
bla
...
```

`fun` is accessible inside `fun` itself, so we can easily call it.

*But what if Python were different, and `fun` weren't accessible
inside `fun`?*

```
> def fun():
>   print "bla"
>   # what to do here? (cannot call fun!)
```

The solution is to pass `fun` itself as an argument to `fun`:

```
> def fun(arg): # fun receives itself as argument
>   print "bla"
>   arg(arg) # to recur, fun calls itself, and passes itself along
```

And Y makes that possible:

```
> def Y(f):
>   f(f)

> Y(fun)
bla
bla
bla
...
```

All it does it call a function with itself as argument.

(I don't know if this definition of Y is 100% correct, but I think it's the general idea.)

Comment: Technically that's the Omega combinator — the actual Y combinator allows the function to take arguments, too :)

Comment: Finally understood the Y-combinator after searching SO for half an hour. The best answers on SO are the ones which are short with only everyday language.

Answer (score 23):

Reginald Braithwaite (aka Raganwald) has been writing a great series on combinators in Ruby over at his new blog, [homoiconic](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/tree/master).

While he doesn't (to my knowledge) look at the Y-combinator itself, he does look at other combinators, for instance:

- the [Kestrel](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/tree/master/2008-10-29/kestrel.markdown)
- the [Thrush](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/tree/master/2008-10-30/thrush.markdown)
- the [Cardinal](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/tree/master/2008-10-31/songs_of_the_cardinal.markdown)
- the [Obdurate Kestrel](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/tree/master%2F2008-11-12%2Fthe_obdurate_kestrel.md)
- other Quirky Birds

and a few posts on how you [can](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/tree/master/2008-11-07/from_birds_that_compose_to_method_advice.markdown) [use](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/tree/master/2008-11-04/quirky_birds_and_meta_syntactic_programming.markdown) them.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that series myself. I need to study the examples a bit more because I'm not fluent in Ruby, but it's great.

Answer (score 15):

Quote Wikipedia:

> A combinator is a higher-order function that uses only function application and earlier defined combinators to define a result from its arguments.

Now what does this mean? It means a combinator is a function (output is determined solely by its input) whose input includes a function as an argument.

What do such functions look like and what are they used for? Here are some examples:

`(f o g)(x) = f(g(x))`

Here `o` is a combinator that takes in 2 functions , `f` and `g`, and returns a function as its result, the composition of `f` with `g`, namely `f o g`.

Combinators can be used to hide logic. Say we have a data type `NumberUndefined`, where `NumberUndefined` can take on a numeric value `Num x` or a value `Undefined`, where `x` a is a `Number`. Now we want to construct addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division for this new numeric type. The semantics are the same as for those of `Number` except if `Undefined` is an input, the output must also be `Undefined` and when dividing by the number `0` the output is also `Undefined`.

One could write the tedious code as below:

```
Undefined +' num = Undefined
num +' Undefined = Undefined
(Num x) +' (Num y) = Num (x + y)

Undefined -' num = Undefined
num -' Undefined = Undefined
(Num x) -' (Num y) = Num (x - y)

Undefined *' num = Undefined
num *' Undefined = Undefined
(Num x) *' (Num y) = Num (x * y)

Undefined /' num = Undefined
num /' Undefined = Undefined
(Num x) /' (Num y) = if y == 0 then Undefined else Num (x / y)
```

Notice how the all have the same logic concerning `Undefined` input values. Only division does a bit more. The solution is to extract out the logic by making it a combinator.

```
comb (~) Undefined num = Undefined
comb (~) num Undefined = Undefined
comb (~) (Num x) (Num y) = Num (x ~ y)

x +' y = comb (+) x y
x -' y = comb (-) x y
x *' y = comb (*) x y
x /' y = if y == Num 0 then Undefined else comb (/) x y
```

This can be generalized into the so-called `Maybe` monad that programmers make use of in functional languages like Haskell, but I won't go there.

Answer (score 6):

A combinator is function with **no free variables**. That means, amongst other things, that the combinator does not have dependencies on things outside of the function, only on the function parameters.

Using F# this is my understanding of combinators:

```
let sum a  b = a + b;; //sum function (lambda)
```

In the above case sum is a combinator because both `a` and `b` are bound to the function parameters.

```
let sum3 a b c = sum((sum a b) c);;
```

The above function is not a combinator as it uses `sum`, which is not a bound variable (i.e. it doesn't come from any of the parameters).

We can make sum3 a combinator by simply passing the sum function as one of the parameters:

```
let sum3 a b c sumFunc = sumFunc((sumFunc a b) c);;
```

This way `sumFunc` is **bound** and hence the entire function is a combinator.

So, this is my understanding of combinators. Their significance, on the other hand, still escapes me. As others pointed out, fixed point combinators allow one to express a recursive function without `explicit` recursion. I.e. instead of calling itself the recusrsive function calls lambda that is passed in as one of the arguments.

Here is one of the most understandable combinator derivations that I found:

http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html

Comment: What about `+` in the definition of `sum`?  It's not bound.

Comment: @MattFenwick at some point you need to talk to the hardware. This kind of what if gets brought up a lot in theory discussions; but it's more of a red herring than anything else. + can't ever be defined in a completely combinatoric way because at some point you need to signal a plus instruction to the underlying implementation. Even SKI calculus doesn't really have a good idea of numbers, and unary implementations require some call to implementation too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160913141703/http://www.dreamsongs.com/NewFiles/WhyOfY.pdf).
The code examples are in scheme, but they shouldn't be hard to follow.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more introductory than the dreamsongs one. Maybe with some more motivation about what problem they address etc.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a good one : http://www.catonmat.net/blog/derivation-of-ycombinator/

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty short on theory, but I can give you an example that sets my imagination aflutter, which may be helpful to you.  The simplest interesting combinator is probably "test".

Hope you know Python

```
tru = lambda x,y: x
fls = lambda x,y: y 

test = lambda l,m,n: l(m,n)
```

Usage:

```
>>> test(tru,"goto loop","break")
'goto loop'
>>> test(fls,"goto loop","break")
'break'
```

test evaluates to the second argument if the first argument is true, otherwise the third.

```
>>> x = tru
>>> test(x,"goto loop","break")
'goto loop'
```

Entire systems can be built up from a few basic combinators.

(This example is more or less copied out of Types and Programming Languages by Benjamin C. Pierce)

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, Y combinator is a higher order function that is used to implement recursion on lambda expressions (anonymous functions). Check the article [How to Succeed at Recursion Without Really Recursing](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html) by Mike Vanier - it's one of best practical explanation of this matter I've seen.

Also, scan the SO archives:

- [What is a y-combinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93526/what-is-a-y-combinator)
- [Y-Combinator Practical Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869497/y-combinator-practical-example)