# What is implicit recursion?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, recursion, lisp, scheme

What is implicit recursion? How is it different from explicit recursion?

Answer (score 6):

I've not seen the term used often.  A Google search revealed a usage in a book on the lambda calculus.  That book is arguing as follows:

1. An equation that claims to be a definition should not include the thing defined on the right-hand side. (I agree with this.)
2. If such an equation, like

   ```
   FAC = \n. if n = 0 then 1 else n * FAC (n-1),
   ```

   does show up, we'll call it "implicit recursion" and say it's illegal. (I'm a bit dubious about this.)

I don't know why this term is considered useful; to me it's just another piece of terminology.  The important thing is to distinguish a true mathematical **definition** from a **recursion equation**, which has to be solved.  Not every recursion equation has a useful or interesting solution; for example, although the factorial function is a solution for `FAC` above, the only useful solution for

```
x = x + 1
```

is "bottom", which may stand for "wrong" or "undefined" or "divergence".

I think the line in the textbook is trying to distinguish between "implicit recursion" (which I would call a recursion equation or a recursive equation) and a mathematical definition that uses an **explicit fixed-point operator** like the Y combinator.

When it comes to practical programming languages, all this discussion is extremely academic.  Programming languages are totally set up to support "implicit recursion", although [explicit fixed-point combinators are also surprisingly useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869497/y-combinator-practical-example).

Comment: I suspect the original poster made up the term, as the opposite of "explicit recursion" (as in the other answer).

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the terms **explicit** and **implicit recursion** to contrast recursive function definitions (explicit), eg:

```
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
sum [] = 0
```

With functions that use explicitly recursive functions like `fold`s and `map`, (implicit), eg:

```
sum xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

Comment: Yup, that is the usual meaning in casual conversation about Haskell.