# How does Jan Willem Klop's "(L L L...)" Y combinator work?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, computer-science

I understand [what a Y Combinator is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93526/what-is-a-y-combinator), but I don't understand this example of a "novel" combinator, from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_combinator):

```
 Yk = (L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L)

Where:

    L = λabcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyzr. (r (t h i s i s a f i x e d p o i n t c o m b i n a t o r))
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 12):

The essence of a fixed-point combinator `C` is that `C f` reduces to `f (C f)`. It doesn't matter what you take for `C` as long as does this. So instead of

```
(\y f. f (y y f)) (\y f. f (y y f))
```

you can just as well take

```
(\y z f. f (y y y f)) (\y z f. f (y y y f)) (\y z f. f (y y y f))
```

Basically you need something of the form

```
C t1 t2 ... tN
```

where `ti = C` for some `i` and

```
C = \x1 x2 .. xN f. f (xi u1 u2 ... xi ... u(N-1) f)
```

The other terms `tj` and `uj` are not actually "used". You can see that Klop's `L` has this form (although he uses the fact that all `ti` are `L` such that the second `xi` can also be any other `xj`).