# Typedef for recursive lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Is there a way to create a `typedef` such that the following (a basic "pure" implementation of the y-combinator) would compile?

```
typedef ??? f;
[](f x){x(x);} ([](f x){x(x);});
```

This has the effect of creating a "recursive lambda", i.e. one which calls itself by using a second lambda to get a reference to itself. `x` in the first lambda is a reference to the second lambda, so `x(x)` calls the second lambda with a reference to itself. Thereafter, the second lambda recurses by calling `x(x)`. This code, when executed, should produce an infinite loop until it hits stack overflow. More sophisticated implementations of the second function can produce arbitrary recursive behaviour.

I have tried `typedef`ing various versions of `void(*)(...)` but I do not believe that can succeed. My template metaprogramming is not strong enough to handle this kind of thing.

Comment: What does `x(x);` suppose to do (assuming it is possible)? Also what does the argument `([](f x){x(x);})` mean and do? Give us some idea as to what you're doing.

Comment: Just recurse. It's a y-combinator.

Comment: @nneonneo: OK, I don't know what a y-combinator is, so I guess my answer looks idiotic. Should that just set up an infinite recursion by calling itself? And are you allowed to define a new class `X`, and then `typedef X f`?

Comment: You cannot create directly-recursive types through a typedef.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Sorry. I expanded the question to define what I am doing. And yeah, a new class is OK.

Comment: I think what are you asking is basically what it was done here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/my-implementation-of-fixed-point-combinator-in-c1x-compiled-under-vistual-stu

Comment: @Pedrom: Interesting. They just defined a functor `loopfunc_t` and a `std::function<...loopfunc_t>`. So that's how you can do a recursive function -- brilliant!

Comment: I thought the C++11 standard says that lambdas cannot be recursive.

Comment: @Nils: where does it say that?

Comment: I don't remember, but thought I read it somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this one?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    template<typename F>
    X(F f) : _f(f)
    { }

    void operator () (std::function<void(X)> f)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling myself..." << std::endl;
        _f(f);
    }

    std::function<void(X)> _f;
};

int main()
{
    typedef X f;
    [](f x){x(x);} ([](f x){x(x);});
}
```

Comment: Hm. Well, it fulfills the letter of the law, if not the spirit (the second lambda is basically unused).

Comment: @nneonneo: You mean the first.

Comment: @Xeo: Hm? The first lambda constructs an `f x` using the second lambda, then calls `x(x)`. But the second lambda is thrown away after being used for construction.

Comment: @nneonneo: Ah, true enough.

Comment: @nneonneo: Second attempt. Any better?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Nice! Yeah, I think this is correct. It implements a recursive functor type.

Comment: (BTW: I ran out of upvotes for today. I will certainly give you a +1 when I get them back tomorrow :P)