# typedef function pointer recursive

Tags: c++, c

I was trying to declare a function that takes a function of the same type as parameter.

```
void rec(void(*f)(void(*)(void(*)(...))))
{
    f(f);
}
```

I ended up making a recursive attempt.

You can always cast from a `void*`.

```
void rec(void* f)
{
    ((void(*)())f)(f);
}
```

But it's not type safe

I attempted to do this with a `typedef`:

```
typedef void(*RecFunc)(RecFunc);
```

But doesn't compile.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: `typedef void(*RecFunc)(RecFunc);` is compiling just fine https://ideone.com/sUtDSL

Comment: Look at what you're setting as the argument to your function in your typedef.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not if you actually try and use the typedef...  RecFunc p = nullptr;

Comment: Related to [recursive std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737449/recursive-typedef-function-definition-stdfunction-returning-its-own-type) and [recursive lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345529/typedef-for-recursive-lambda)

Comment: @rmawatson I just did. See it again https://ideone.com/sUtDSL

Comment: I think the answer might be different for C and C++

Comment: @EugeneSh. The error from clang-C++ is *"error: unknown type name 'RecFunc'"* and the error from clang-C is *"error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition"* So one explanation is that you're compiling with a C compiler that defaults the parameter type to `int`.

Comment: It does, and then it doesn't: https://ideone.com/0Cq6mC  :) turns out it is OK in C, but not in C++.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, I guess it could happen.. So it is UB as interpreting `int` as a function pointer.

Comment: you get a warning in c.  That is interesting though.  In C, it is OK because it's a loophole.  You can define function arguments without type.  int foo(bar) is ok.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting! I was compiling with gcc C++14. I guess it's a case where C++ is not backwards compatible?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do what you are trying to do. As you noticed, you ended up trying to make a recursive `typedef`. That is not supported by the language.

Comment: He's really asking about a recursive function declaration (typedef is just the mechanism) - also not allowed AFAIK, not that I've ever tried.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Try using `typedef void (*RefFunc)(RecFun f);`.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I didn't follow the *`h` is passed* bit.

Comment: @EugeneSh., gcc is doing something strange there. With `-Wall`, it prints a waring *parameter names (without types) in function declaration* and proceeds to build the program. However, if I change the `typedef` to `typedef void(*RecFunc)(int RecFunc);` it fails to build. Somebody with deep knowledge of `gcc` might be able to explain its behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Looks like that doesn't compile in C++...wonder why.

Comment: @RSahu, if it is just an identifier without type, it is the deprecated K&R form of function declaration, I think.

Comment: @JensGustedt, Wasn't `int` assumed as the default type if it wasn't specified?

Comment: @RSahu, 30 years ago, perhaps.

Comment: @JensGustedt, what can be implied type these days?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this directly in a conformant manner, but you can if you put the function pointer in a wrapper struct:

```
struct F;
typedef void(*RecFunc)(struct F *);

struct F {
    RecFunc f;
};
```

We first forward declare the struct so the typedef can use it.  Then we define the struct to contain the function pointer.  In this case the resursive function type is defined to take a pointer to `struct F`, but it will still work if it takes an instance of `struct F`.

Then you can use it like this:

```
void f(struct F *sf)
{
    static int x=5;

    if (x) {
        printf("x=%d\n",x);
        x--;
        sf->f(&(struct F){f});
    }
}

int main()
{
    f(&(struct F){f});
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x=5
x=4
x=3
x=2
x=1
```

Comment: You are not using `sf->f`. Was that on purpose?

Comment: @RSahu It was not.  Fixed.