# Decoding a Cryptic Python statement

Tags: python

I saw this on a job ad (on SO):

```
lambda f: (lambda a: a(a))(lambda b: f(lambda *args: b(b)(*args)))
```

So what I understand is it is an anonymous (unnamed) function, which is composed of two further nested anonymous functions. The innermost function takes a variable list of arguements (*args).

I can't work out what is it supposed to do. Is this something that would actually work or is it impossible to tell without seeing the actual list of args?

Comment: Are you sure it's *supposed* to do anything?

Comment: I would second @mhlester's suggestion that it is a sick joke. With a potential to cause endless recursion?!

Comment: It might not be clear what the code does but it's clear what the manager has to do: Fire the programmer and get someone who writes readable code.

Comment: Perhaps they are expecting a potential candidate to say this is rubbish code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've undone the lambdas just to make it a little easier to read. Here's the code using nested functions:

```
def f1(f):
    def f2(a):
        return a(a)

    def f3(b):
        def f4(*args):
            return b(b)(*args)

        return f(f4)

    return f2(f3)
```

This would be equivalent basically to:

```
f1 = lambda f: (lambda a: a(a))(lambda b: f(lambda *args: b(b)(*args)))
```

Now let's follow the function calls. First you're going to call f1 with some argument. Then the following is going to happen:

1. f2 gets called with f3
2. f2 returns f3 called with itself as a parameter
3. Now we're inside f3 with b being f3
4. f3 return f (the parameter you called f1 with) with f4 as the parameter
5. f is a callback that gets called with a function as its only parameter
6. If f calls this function then its call will be applied to the result of b called with b. b is f3, so f would essentially be calling the result of f3(f3) which is what f is going to return

Therefore f1 can be reduced to:

```
def f1(f):
    def f3():
        def f4(*args):
            return f3()(*args)
        return f(f4)

    return f3()
```

Now I've come up with a way to call f1 that doesn't end in infinite recursion:

```
called = False

def g1(func):
    def g2(*args):
        print args
        return None

    global called

    if not called:
        called = True
        func(5)
    else:
        return g2

f1(g1) # prints "(5,)"
```

As you can see, it uses a global to stop the recursion.

Here's another example that runs trials of a Poisson distribution with lambda (lambda is a parameter to the Poisson distribution, not the lambda operator) of 10:

```
import random

def g3(func):
    def g4(a):
        def g5(b):
            print a
            return a+b
        return g5

    if random.random() < 0.1:
        return g4(1)
    else:
        return g4(func(1))

f1(g3)
```

And finally something deterministic, not depending on a global, and actually somewhat interesting:

```
def g6(func):
    def g7(n):
        if n > 0:
            return n*func(n-1)
        else:
            return 1

    return g7

print f1(g6)(5) # 120
print f1(g6)(6) # 720
```

I'm sure everyone can guess what this function is, but pretty interesting that you can actually get this strange lambda expression to do something useful.

Comment: `function` should be replaced with `def`.

Comment: You should define `f3` outside `f2` but inside `f1`.

Answer (score 6):

The code is creating [Y-combinator in Python](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Python). This is merely an excercise, not a real world code; don't try to decrypt it.

To understand what Y-combinator itself does, you may refer to this SO question: [What is a y-combinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93526/what-is-a-y-combinator) and to its wikipedia page: [Fixed-point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator).

Maybe this ad is looking for people that know functional programming and/or advanced computer science topics like [Lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [Combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic), which are primary theoretical foundation behind functional programming.

Or maybe their company is [Y Combinator winner startup](http://ycombinator.com/about.html), and they are merely looking for Python programmers with CS background.

Answer (score 3):

Not just *args, it's hard to tell what it is without knowing what `a`, `b`, `f`, **and** `*args` are.

The rabbit hole goes especially deep when b is passed as argument to function b, and that result is a function to which args is passed.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite equivalent, without too much nesting:

```
def f1(f):
    def f2(a): return a(a)
    def f3(b):
        def f4(*args): return b(b)(*args)
        return f(f4)
    return f2(f3)
```

`f2` can be replaced, so we get

```
def f1(f):
    def f3(b):
        def f4(*args): return b(b)(*args)
        return f(f4)
    return f3(f3) # was f2(f3)
```

`f3` is always called with itself, so we replace `b` with `f3`:

```
def f1(f):
    def f3():
        def f4(*args): return f3()(*args)
        return f(f4)
    return f3()
```

So what does it do?

We see `f3()` returns whatever `f` returns, and this is supposed to be called with an arbitrary number of arguments.

`f` is supposed to take a function taking another function with `*args` and returning such a function.

Calling `f1(f)` returns whatever `f(f4)` returns.

Let's test it:

- With `f=lambda ff: lambda *args: ff(*args)`, `f1(f)()` gives us an infinite recursion.
- `f=lambda ff: lambda *args: (ff, args)` doesn't call the given function, so we can safely play with it:

  - `f1(f)(4)` gives us a tuple `(f4, (4,))`.
  - If we use that tuple's 0th element: `f1(f)(4)[0](1)`, we get `(f4, (1,))`.