# Understanding Y Combinator through generic lambdas

Tags: c++, recursion, functional-programming, c++14, y-combinator

While building a small lambda-based metaprogramming library, I had the necessity of using recursion in a C++14 generic lambda, to implement a [left-fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

My own solution was passing the lambda itself as one of its parameters, like this:

```
template <typename TAcc, typename TF, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto fold_l_impl(TAcc acc, TF f, Ts... xs)
{
    // Folding step.
    auto step([=](auto self)
    {
        return [=](auto y_acc, auto y_x, auto... y_xs)
        {
            // Compute next folding step.
            auto next(f(y_acc, y_x));

            // Recurse if required.
            return static_if(not_empty(y_xs...))
                .then([=]
                    {
                        // Recursive case.
                        return self(self)(next, y_xs...);
                    })
                .else_([=]
                    {
                        // Base case.
                        return next;
                    })();
        };
    });

    // Start the left-fold.
    return step(step)(acc, xs...);
}
```

`step` is the "main" lambda that starts off the recursion. It returns a function with the desired left-fold signature *(accumulator, current item, remaining items...)*.

The function calls itself recursively by using `self(self)(next, y_xs...)`.

I've recently come across [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0200r0.html) that wants to add a **Y Combinator** to the Standard Library, and after reading it, it seems extremely similar to what I am doing here.

Unfortunately, the concept of the Y Combinator still doesn't "click" for me - I am missing something and I cannot visualize how to generalize what I did with the `self` parameter for any function, avoiding the `step` boilerplate.

I've read [this excellent StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93526/what-is-a-y-combinator) regarding the matter, but it still didn't "click" for me.

*(From that answer)* a recursive factorial is defined this way:

```
fact =
  (recurs) =>
    (x) =>
      x == 0 ? 1 : x * recurs(x - 1);
```

The `recurs` parameter seems to have the same role as my `self` parameter. What I do not understand is how `recurs` is called without passing `recurs` into itself again.

I have to call `self` like this: `self(self)(params...)`.

`recurs`, however, is called like `recurs(params...)`.

Attempting to call `self(params...)` results in a compiler error informing me that `self` requires only a single parameter *(which is the `auto self` lambda parameter)*.

What am I missing here? How could I rewrite my `fold_l_impl` lambda in such a way that its recursion could be generalized through the use of a Y Combinator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a y combinate where the lambda is passed a recurs that doesn't need to be passed recurs:

```
template<class F>
struct y_combinate_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&...args)const {
    return f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
template<class F>
y_combinate_t<std::decay_t<F>> y_combinate( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
};
```

then you do:

```
  return y_combinate(step)(acc, xs...);
```

and change

```
                   return self(self)(next, y_xs...);
```

to

```
                   return self(next, y_xs...);
```

the trick here is I used a non-lambda function object that has access to its own `this`, which I pass to `f` as its first parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now! It "clicked" when I realized that what I wanted to do was get the `*this` of a lambda, which is not possible at the moment.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo As an aside, self should be taken as `auto&& self` not `auto self`.

Comment: Why `std::decay_t<F>`? Is it important to copy `f`?

Comment: @Barry Because I'm storing it and returning it?  Storing and returning a reference deduced from a function argument in generic code is a bad idea, in my experience.  Imagine `auto fib(){ auto internal = [](auto&& self, int x){ if (x<2) return 1; return self(x-1)+self(x-2); }; return y_combinate(internal); }` -- we want the lambda to live as long as the return type, not only as long as `internal`.

Comment: @Yakk Maybe that's just a general language limitation then. On the one hand, sometimes you make unnecessary copies. On the other hand, sometimes you dangle references?

Comment: @Barry Yes.  If we could add in a "return value lifetime depends upon lifetime of argument" it would help; but even then, it doesn't solve the `fib()` code above (where the returned object needs to be *bigger* and carry the lambda with it!) other than possibly generating a warning (returning value whose lifetime depends on a temporary).  However, if a caller wants to avoid creating that copy, they can `y_combinate(std::cref(f))`, and the returned function object will only hold a (constant reference to) `f`, not a copy, and it will work.