# Recursively visiting an `std::variant` using lambdas and fixed-point combinators

Tags: c++, lambda, variant, c++17, boost-hana

I would like to visit a *"recursive"* `std::variant` using lambdas and overload-creating functions *(e.g. `boost::hana::overload`)*.

---

Let's assume I have a variant type called `my_variant` which can store one an `int`, a `float` or a `vector<my_variant>`:

```
struct my_variant_wrapper;

using my_variant = 
    std::variant<int, float, std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>>;

struct my_variant_wrapper 
{
    my_variant _v;
};
```

*(I'm using a wrapper `my_variant_wrapper` class in order to define the variant type recursively.)*

---

I want to recursively visit the variant printing different things depending on the stored types. Here's a [working example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/APnjkmINT2xrnCYR) using a `struct`-based visitor:

```
struct struct_visitor
{
    void operator()(int x) const { std::cout << x << "i\n"; }
    void operator()(float x) const { std::cout << x << "f\n"; }

    void operator()(const std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>& x) const 
    { 
        for(const auto& y : x) std::visit(*this, y._v); 
    }
};
```

Calling `std::visit` with the above visitor prints the desired output:

```
my_variant v{
    std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>{
        my_variant_wrapper{45}, 
        std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>{
            my_variant_wrapper{1}, my_variant_wrapper{2}
        },
        my_variant_wrapper{33.f}
    }
};

std::visit(struct_visitor{}, v);

// Prints: 
/*
    45i
    1i
    2i
    33f
*/
```

---

I would like to locally create the visitor as a series of overloaded lambdas using [`boost::hana::overload`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/overload_8hpp.html) and [`boost::hana::fix`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/fix_8hpp.html).

`fix` is an implementation of the [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator), which can be used to implement recursion in type-deduced lambdas. *(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608977/understanding-y-combinator-through-generic-lambdas) for more information.)*

This is what I tried, and expected to work:

```
namespace bh = boost::hana;
auto lambda_visitor = bh::fix([](auto self, const auto& x)
    {
        bh::overload(
            [](int y){ std::cout << y << "i\n"; },
            [](float y){ std::cout << y << "f\n"; },
            [&self](const std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>& y)
            {
                for(const auto& z : y) std::visit(self, z._v);  
            })(x);
    });
```

My reasoning is as follows:

- `boost::hana::fix` returns an unary generic lambda that can be used as the visitor for an `std::variant`.
- `boost::hana::fix` takes a binary generic lambda where the first parameter is an unary function that allows recursion of the lambda, and the second parameter is the initial argument for the body of the lambda.
- Calling `boost::hana::overload` with handlers for all the possible types inside `my_variant` creates some sort of visitor which is equivalent to `struct_visitor`.
- Using `self` instead of `lambda_visitor` inside the `const std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>&` overload should allow recursion to work properly.
- Immediately calling the created overload with `bh::overload(...)(x)` should trigger the recursive visitation.

Unfortunately, [as you can see in this *wandbox* example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Gai1oolMCMZq1K86), the `lambda_visitor` example fails to compile, spewing out a lot of almost-undecipherable template-heavy errors:

> ...
>
> /usr/local/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/hana/functional/fix.hpp:74:50: error: use of 'main():: [with auto:2 = boost::hana::fix_t >; auto:3 = int]' before deduction of 'auto'
>            { return f(fix(f), static_cast(x)...); }
>
> ...

---

The error seems similar to what I would get without using `boost::hana::fix`:

```
auto lambda_visitor = bh::overload(
    [](int y){ std::cout << y << "i\n"; },
    [](float y){ std::cout << y << "f\n"; },
    [](const std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>& y)
    {
        for(const auto& z : y) std::visit(lambda_visitor, z._v);  
    });

std::visit(lambda_visitor, v);
```

> error: use of 'lambda_visitor' before deduction of 'auto'
>                        for(const auto& z : y) std::visit(lambda_visitor, z._v);

---

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve local *recursive variant visitation* using `fix`, `overload` and a set of lambdas?

My intuition was that `lambda_visitor` would have been *"equivalent"* to `struct_visitor`, thanks to the indirection offered by `fix`.

Comment: GCC HEAD [fails to compile even the most basic example of `boost::hana::fix`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P8B4X36hxbpv2FwS) (GCC 6.1 and Clang HEAD work fine), so I think the problem here is utterly unrelated to `std::variant`. It would be interesting to try Clang HEAD with libstdc++ HEAD, but I don't know how to do that on wandbox even though all the bits are obviously present...

Comment: You can set '-stdlib=libstdc++' in the "compiler options" section. It seems to compile properly with clang, after getting rid of iostreams.

Comment: "*You can set '-stdlib=libstdc++' in the "compiler options" section.*" You can, [but it doesn't appear to actually do anything](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yEQ1kdCEv8dgbbc3)... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn I stand corrected!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's pick a simpler example. We want to implement `gcd` using the fix-point combinator. First go might be something like:

```
auto gcd = bh::fix([](auto self, int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : self(b, a%b);
});

std::cout << gcd(12, 18);
```

This fails to compile with gcc ultimately producing this error:

```
/usr/local/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/hana/functional/fix.hpp:74:50: error: use of 'main()::<lambda(auto:2, int, int)> [with auto:2 = boost::hana::fix_t<main()::<lambda(auto:2, int, int)> >]' before deduction of 'auto'
         { return f(fix(f), static_cast<X&&>(x)...); }
                                                  ^
```

The lambda we're passing to `fix()` has a deduced return type. But how do we deduce it? There's only a single return statement, and that one is recursive! We need to give the compiler some help. Either we need to break apart our `return` statement so that one has a clear type:

```
auto gcd = bh::fix([](auto self, int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return self(b, a%b);
    }
});
```

or simply provide the return type explicitly:

```
auto gcd = bh::fix([](auto self, int a, int b) -> int {
    return b == 0 ? a : self(b, a%b);
});
```

Both of these options compile and work.

The same is true of your original example. If you just specify that the lambda returns `void`, everything works:

```
auto lambda_visitor = bh::fix([](auto self, const auto& x) -> void
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^
    {
        bh::overload(
            [](int y){ std::cout << y << "i\n"; },
            [](float y){ std::cout << y << "f\n"; },
            [&self](const std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>& y)
            {
                for(const auto& z : y) std::visit(self, z._v);  
            })(x);
    });

std::visit(lambda_visitor, v);
```

Comment: So what's the problem [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P8B4X36hxbpv2FwS) then?

Comment: @ildjarn Could be a gcc regression, I filed a bug report. Using [this y combinator](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/572/lambdas/8508/recursive-lambdas) so as to avoid the hana dependency, I can get factorial to compile on gcc 4.9, 5.3, and 6.1, but not 7.0.