# How does F# implement let rec?

Tags: recursion, parameters, f#, scheme

I am wondering how F# implements `let rec`, and I couldn't find an answer. As a preface, I'll address how Scheme implements `letrec`:

1. In Scheme, `let` is just syntactics sugar for a definition of a lambda and applying it:

`(let ((x 1)) (+ x 2))`

is transformed to

`((lambda (x) (+ x 2)) 1)`

(in each case the expression is evaluated to `3`).

2. `letrec` is also syntactic sugar, but `#f` is passed as initial argument to the lambda's parameters, and `set!` expressions are injected before the `letrec` body, like in this transformation:

`(letrec ((x 1)) (+ x 2)) => ((lambda (x) (begin (set! x 1) (+ x 2))) #f)`.

Considering that F# doesn't have an equivalent operator to Scheme's `set!`, how does it implement `let rec`? Does it declare the function's parameters as `mutable`, and then mutate them in the function's body?

Comment: You're assuming same (or similar) underlying machinery, which isn't the case. F# works on CLR, which has different machinery. In particular, all functions are defined before execution begins. And yes, F# does have an equivalent of `set!`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, in what way are the functions defined before execution? What is being defined?

Comment: Function name, parameters, result type, and code body is defined. All of this is defined during compilation, waaay before execution starts.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, what is F#'s equivalent of `set!`?

Comment: I don't know Scheme, can you provide a reference with more details on this. I am considering answering this question, but want more touch points than what you have provided.

Comment: Of interest: [Fixed point combinators in lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus)

Comment: Of interest: [What is a y-combinator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93526/what-is-a-y-combinator)

Comment: Of interest: [Fixed-point combinators in JavaScript: Memoizing recursive functions](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-recursive-fixed-point-y-combinator-in-javascript-for-memoization/)

Comment: Of interest: [The Y Combinator](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html) - Uses Scheme as the example language.

Comment: Of interest: [Understanding, at last, the Y Combinator - a programmer-friendly perspective](http://hisham.hm/2011/04/04/understanding-at-last-the-y-combinator-a-programmer-friendly-perspective/)

Comment: The equivalent of `set!` in F# is the destructive update operator: `let mutable x = 0; x <- 5` Here are some examples: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fsharp/fsharp_mutable_data.htm

Comment: Are you trying to understand the concepts for recursive functions, or how a recursive function's parameters are created and used with F#? If you are just interested in how the recursive function's parameters are created and used then I think you are missing the bigger and more helpful concept of what is a recursive function and why do most functional languages require the `rec` keyword and what are the origins of `rec`

Comment: Of interest: [THAT ABOUT WRAPS IT UP Using FIX to Handle Errors Without Exceptions, and Other Programming Tricks](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/97/ECS-LFCS-97-375/ECS-LFCS-97-375.pdf) More for my personal use, but still useful for others.

Comment: Of interest: [(Y Y) Works!](https://xivilization.net/~marek/binaries/Y.pdf) Gives a practical example of inventing the Y combinator.

Comment: Of interest: [Foundations of Functional Programming](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Notes/Founds-FP.pdf) - Only if you like theory. Does a nice job of building up Lambda Calculus to functional programming including the Y Combinator.

Comment: Of interest: [AN INTRODUCTION TO FUNCTIONAL PROGRAMMING THROUGH LAMBDA CALCULUS](https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/library/functional_programming/gjm.lambook88.pdf) - Buy the book if you use it a lot. This is one of my favorites and an easier read than `Foundations of Functional Programming`

Comment: AFAIK, the Scheme standard(s) don't require any particular implementation of either `let` or `letrec`. There are macro implementations, but those are just suggestions.

Comment: in Scheme, it is not `#f` but a special `#<invalid-value>` that must be used initially, so that any attempt at getting its *value* before it is set, is an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In F#, `let rec` allows a reference to the binding from within the function before it has been bound. `let rec` doesn't have an implementation per se, because it is merely a compiler hint.

In this contrived example,

```
let rec even =
    function 0 -> true  | 1 -> false | x -> odd (x - 1)
and odd =
    function 0 -> false | 1 -> true  | x -> even (x - 1)
```

the compiled IL very unglamorously translates to:

```
public static bool even(int _arg1)
{
    switch (_arg1)
    {
    case 0:
        return true;
    case 1:
        return false;
    default:
        return odd(_arg1 - 1);
    }
}

public static bool odd(int _arg2)
{
    switch (_arg2)
    {
    case 0:
        return false;
    case 1:
        return true;
    default:
        return even(_arg2 - 1);
    }
}
```

All function definitions are statically compiled to IL. 
F# ultimately is a language which runs on the CLR. 
There is no meta-programming.

Comment: "*There is no meta-programming.*" Not in this case, but F# does have metaprogramming despite being [CLI](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)-based (the CLR is an implementation, not a specification).

Comment: @ildjarn F# does have some forms of meta-programming, but I meant that it is quite unlike the kind found in scheme or lisp.