# (self self) call inside the let statement, in strict language

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, let, y-combinator

I am currently, going through [this article](https://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html) on Y-combinator by [Mike Vanier](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~mvanier/).

Along the way of Y-combinator derivation, this code:

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0)

      1
      (* n ((self self) (- n 1))))))

((part-factorial part-factorial) 5) ==> 120
(define factorial (part-factorial part-factorial))
(factorial 5) ==> 120
```

is worked out to:

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  (let ((f (self self)))
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (f (- n 1)))))))

(define factorial (part-factorial part-factorial))
(factorial 5) ==> 120
```

After that, article states:

> This will work fine in a lazy language. In a strict language, the `(self self)` call in the let statement will send us into an infinite loop, because in order to calculate `(part-factorial part-factorial)` (in the definition of factorial) you will first have to calculate (part-factorial part-factorial) (in the `let` expression).

and then reader is challenged:

> For fun: figure out why this wasn't a problem with the previous definition.

It seems to me I've figured out why, though I would like to confirm that:

1. I am correct in my understanding.
2. I don't miss any critical points, in my understanding.

My understanding is: in the first code snippet `(self self)` call won't result into infinite loop, because it is contained (wrapped) into `lambda` as a `part-factorial` function, and thus evaluated to `lambda (n)` until the call to `(self self)` is actually made, which happens only for `n > 0`. Thus, after `(= n 0)` evaluates to `#t`, there is no need in calling `(self self)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the *"let-over-lambda"* in the second definition

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  (let ((f (self self)))        ; let above the
    (lambda (n)                    ; lambda
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (f (- n 1)))))))
```

causes the application `(self self)` to be triggered before the `(lambda (n) ...)` can be returned.

This suggests another way to avoid the looping: put the problematic self-application itself behind *its own* `lambda`:

```
(define (part-factorial self)
  (let ((f (lambda (a) ((self self) a))))
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (f (- n 1)))))))
```

and now this works, too. It is known as *"eta-expansion"* (or "eta-conversion" in general, as its dual is "eta-contraction").

*This* way is what's actually used in the usual "applicative-order Y-combinator" definition.

In the first definition the `(self self)` application is only triggered when its result is actually needed — but the cost to it is that we had to write it in a somewhat "unnatural" style, which is in any case different from what we'd like to write, i.e. just use  `f` to refer to the function which is somehow made recursive for us *behind the scenes*.

With the explicit self-application the burden is on us, and we humans are known to err. To err is human, after all, as to forgive — Divine; but our computers are not at that all-forgiving stage *quite yet*.

So, *this* is  the why of Y. To let us write it straight, without worries, with the details factored out and abstracted safely away.

And the *burden* of explicit self-application shall be mentioned no more.

Comment: wisdom of the heavens

Comment: @naomik [sacrilege](https://www.google.com/search?q=And+the+burden+shall+be+mentioned+no+more), you mean. :)

Comment: @naomik but seriously, Y is pretty simple (well, at least comprehensible), if presented gradually, with proper motivational examples. Makes me mad really, for all the countless presentations of it as a given, wholly incomprehensible, out of the blue, with no explanations at all. Why do people do it? Or was it just my bad luck? :) /venting

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's the right answer.  And indeed this trick (wrapping something that would otherwise recurse in a lambda) is critical when defining Y for applicative-order languages, which I think his article talks about (it's a good article by the way).