# LINQ using C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to get started learning LINQ in C#.net.

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322/all-about-linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)!

Its a great way to learn LINQ, supports LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects and LINQ to XML, and it comes preloaded with 200+ examples from the book [C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/).

Comment: Good to know. Very nice. I wish it could generate Linq from a sql statement (perhaps it can and I don't know how).

Comment: @asp316: LinqPad can't, but you can!, you only have to learn the syntax, and have some practice...

Answer (score 6):

LINQ is a pretty big subject.

I would start with [Hooked On LINQ](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/)

The way I learned Linq was from the book [Linq in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988169)

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN Getting Started With LINQ Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The videos at http://www.asp.net/learn/ are great. They have an entire section on Linq that will take you from "new solution" to fully working examples.

http://www.asp.net/learn/linq-videos/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a long-time SQL developer, and I found that all I needed for the transition to learning LINQ was [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) off of msdn.  All the basics are there, if you understand the generalities of a query-based syntax already.  I don't know what your existing expertise is, so thought I'd throw that out there.