# Is there any applications available to write linq query and execute?

Tags: linq

Best way to learn linq? Is there any applications available to write linq query and execute? 
Can any one suggest

Comment: Are you mainly doing this just against regular C# objects like lists, or SQL? I think the syntax may be mostly the same or similar in both instances, just wondering.

Comment: What are you looking for? Linq2sql, just general linq (lambda's and delegates) or the syntax for `var x = select....`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning about LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322/learning-about-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This REALLY seems like a question for Google. Having said that:

Take a look at: LINQPad: http://www.linqpad.net/.

Also see: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 8):

Check out [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It lets you query a DB directly using a linq query

Comment: yes. If you go to the site, you can download it there for free