# Select only such items that contain any element in int array

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Assume I have a class:

```
public class Item
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<int> ClientsIds { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code:

```
List<Item> items = GetItems();
int[] ids = GetIds();
```

Now I need to select only such items that contain any element in ids int array. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use LINQ. Did you try any of their methods?

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16322/1715004

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a simple `Where` should do it:

```
var filteredItems = items.Where(item => 
                      item.ClientIds.Any(ids.Contains)).ToList();
```

I don't see a need for an extension method here, but you could of course encapsulate it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> FilterItems(this IEnumerable<Item> source, IEnumerable<int> filter)
{
    return source.Where(item => item.ClientIds.Any(filter.Contains));
}
```