# Converting Gridview into CSV

Tags: vb.net, csv

Is this possible to take delimeter other than comma for converting into CSV file....because in my scenario my gridview cell contains data with commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the 'C' in **C**‍SV does stand for "Comma".

That said, depending on what the purpose/destination of your "CSV" output is, I can see two options:

- If your program is the only recipient, use whatever you like. Heck, something like the built in serialises might be easier.
- Otherwise, follow the CSV format and double quote your values.

There is a lot a more useful information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/csv-string-handling) one.

Comment: Thanks Fowl.....the link you provided helps me alot.Actually i am exporting gridview data into CSV format it works fine but the problem arise when grid's column data contain Comma itself like "Calcitrol, 0.25 microgram"..now i put it in double quotes and it works fine.. thanks